# Nuget Package - Properties - Path is not set

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2019 referencing several nuget packages.

[image]

Further down the list, is one package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions which seems to be broken.

[image]

Looking at its properties, I see that the path to the repository is empty, also the version is 0:

[image]

I already tried uninstall and install and the -reinstall option in the command line:

[image]

Unfortunately with the same result.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: The reinstall should have fixed it if it's a hintpath problem, but check your csproj and check if the hintpath to the dll is correct to the dll in the solution packages folder. The project system not being able to find the dll on disk is the only reason I know of that it doesn't show the assembly properties. Assuming the reason you're looking into this is because your project doesn't build or run correctly, migrating to PackageReference makes this hintpath class of problem go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by moving the repository from my users folder to a new folder I created. To make it very short I named it `C:\R\`.

It seems the lenghty filepath could not be resolved. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions is the nuget package with the longest name which brought us to the idea it could be related to some path issue.

After moving the repository to `C:\R\` everything works fine.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information. It's  just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2):

The content in Properties Window(UI) is corresponding to the content in your project file. It seems for some reason your project can't load the assembly successfully. Please check the reference format in your project file.

Open your project file and check the reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package.

Make sure its format is:

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I assume maybe you've modified the project file and by accident changed the right format, for me, I just change the version from `2.2.0.0` to `0.0.0.0` and get the same behavior.

Also, since you're using the Packages.config format, please make sure the right format in it:  `<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />`

Comment: Thank you for the input. It is good input but in my case the reason was a different one. See my answer below.